# How do I move an item on its axis when its rotated?

Tags: modeling

I'm not totally sure how to word this so I'll do my best.

Im trying to animate a gun, and when I want the stock to move while the character is shooting the gun, I wanna move the stock.

Basically, I wanna move the stock with the rotation instead of it just going on the regular axis.

I'm not good at explaining this, if I used the words in the wrong way then I'm sorry.

[image: The Stock is floating.]

Basically, what I'm trying to explain is when I rotate something and then move it, its on the normal grid axis instead of what its facing when its rotated.

[image: As you can see, the line is not where its facing.]

The green line from this brick isn't facing the same way as the brick.

Comment: hello, it's not clear how you want to move the stock, maybe show some drawings with position A, B, C, etc of the stock?

Comment: @moonboots I edited the post, maybe that'll help.

Comment: if you want to move it on its Y axis you need to press G then Y twice as explained by primelf, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to describe is moving along the local axis. Assuming you haven't applied the rotation of the model, you should be able to press `g` to move the model and then the axis you want to move on *TWICE*. When you press the axis key twice it goes in that local axis rather than in the world view.

I can go ahead and include some images if you need! Let me know if this helps you out.